# How to impersonate a IOrganizationService

Tags: crm, impersonation, microsoft-dynamics

Once a IOrganizationService object is instanciated, it´s possible to impersonate?

Better...

**How to impersonate a instanciated IOrganizationService object?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(someUserId);
```

Comment: What is your usecase? With this you can have whatever userid you want as parameter.

Comment: I have a IOrganizationService from a OrganizationServiceProxy.



OrganizationServiceProxy _provider = crmHelper.GetOrganizationProxy();
return (IOrganizationService)_provider;



I can impersonate the OrganizationServiceProxy but not the IOrganizationService.